# What is the list of one member from each equivalence relation in this context?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Good afternoon, I have a question: Let $X = \{1, 2,\dots, 10\}$. Define a relation $R$ on $X \times X$ by $(a, b)R(c, d)$ if $a + d = b + c$. Show that R is an equivalence relation on $X \times X$ and list one member from each equivalence class of $X \times X$.

So, I was able to demonstrate that R is an equivalence relation but I don't understand the last part, what is a list of one member from each equivalence class of $X \times X$? I searched the definition but I still don't get it... Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: An equivalence relation yields equivalence classes. Write down those equivalence classes (or just imagine them being written down, if you're up for it). Now pick one element from each of those classes. That's the solution.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what is an equivalence class?

Comment: Your book (or whatever you have) doesn't explain equivalence classes? That's really strange. If that's really the case, then it's cruel of them to give you this exercise.

Comment: An equivalence class is, informally (and even formally!), the "maximal set of elements that are in relation with each other". Every equivalence relation breaks up the whole set into those equivalence classes: each element belongs to exactly one of those classes, all the elements *within* the class are in relation with each other, and no element from one class is in relation with any elements from any other class.

Answer (score 2):

You are being asked to provide elements such that:

- (a) They are not in the relation with each other, but
- (b) Every element of $X\times X$ is in relation with at least one of those (and then by (a) with exactly one of those).

The answer can be, for example:

$$(10,1), (9,1),(8,1),(7,1),(6,1),(5,1),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9)$$

Notice your relation is nothing else but this: $(a,b)R(c,d)\iff a-b=c-d$. The pairs above make up all the differences from $9$ to $-9$. This means no two of them can be equivalent, and any pair $(a,b)$ is equivalent to exactly one of them - the one having the same difference $a-b$. For example, the pair $(5,2)$ is equivalent with the pair above with the difference $5-2=3$, which is $(4,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

So, according to definition, the equivalence class of $(a,b) \in X \times X$ is:
\begin{equation*}
[(a,b)]_{R} = \{(c,d) \in X \times X \hspace{.2cm} | \hspace{.2cm} (a,b)R(c,d) \}
\end{equation*}
To list a member from each equivalence is no more than the direct aplication of the definition above. As an extra, i would suggest every equivalence class, and then picking one member of each. I will give an example:
\begin{align*}
[(1,1)]_{R} = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),\dots,(10,10)\}
\end{align*}
I obtained this with the procedure below:
\begin{align*}
(1,1)R(c,d) \Leftrightarrow 1 + d = 1 + c \Leftrightarrow c = d
\end{align*}

What you have to do now is to calculate the remainder equivalence classes and then pick one member of each. Also, note that $$[(1,1)]_{R} = [(2,2)]_{R} = \dots = [(10,10)]_{R}$$
And so, you don't need to calculate those. (This is a general result, appliable in the rest of the equivalence classes aswell)